# C Program Limit the integer input range

Tags: c, input, integer, range

I am a new C programming learner, I am trying to make a program which would calculate the GPA of a student on the basis of grade marks input and credits of a subject.

1. The problem I am having is I want to limit the number of subjects input from 2 to 6 only.
2. Another problem is I want to limit the user to input integer from 1 to 100 only, instead of any other keywords, special characters (EOF)

I have put the **"###" in comment line** where I require these modifications.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    // input      user input -- hopefully a number
    // temp       used to collect garbage characters
    // status     did the user enter a number?
    // counter    for keeping track of loop repetition
    // no         no. of subjects to be entered by user.
    // credits    credits per subject 
    // grades     grades acheived in each subject (1 to 100).
    // grade_value  for holding the value of each subject grade (for ex; 80 to hundred is 4.0)
    // grade_points  Grade points for each subject (credits * grade_value)
    // sum         sum of total grade points
    int counter = 1, subjects, no, credits, grades, status, temp;
    float grade_value, grade_point, sum;
    printf("Enter number of subjects you took for current semester: ");
    status = scanf("%d", & no);

    // ### I want to limit this integer input to be >=2 && <=6.

    while (status != 1) {
        while ((temp = getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        if ((temp < 2) && (temp > 6));
        break;
        printf("Invalid input... please enter the number of subject again: ");
        status = scanf("%d", & no);

    }
    // ### I want to be this input to block other character inputs than integer from 1 to hundred.
    while (counter <= no) {
        printf("\nEnter Subject %d grades separated with credits \n", counter);
        scanf("%d %d", & grades, & credits);
        if ((grades > 0) && (grades <= 29)) {
            grade_value = 0;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 30) && (grades <= 34)) {
            grade_value = 0.67;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 35) && (grades <= 39)) {
            grade_value = 1;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 40) && (grades <= 44)) {
            grade_value = 1.33;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 45) && (grades <= 49)) {
            grade_value = 1.67;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf(" \nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 50) && (grades <= 54)) {
            grade_value = 2;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 55) && (grades <= 59)) {
            grade_value = 2.33;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 60) && (grades <= 64)) {
            grade_value = 2.67;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 65) && (grades <= 69)) {
            grade_value = 3;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 70) && (grades <= 74)) {
            grade_value = 3.33;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 75) && (grades <= 79)) {
            grade_value = 3.67;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        } else if ((grades >= 80) && (grades <= 100)) {
            grade_value = 4;
            printf("Grade value for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_value);
            grade_point = credits * grade_value;
            printf("\nGrade point for subject %d is: %.2f", counter, grade_point);
            sum = sum + grade_point;
            ++counter;
        }
        // To print a message if user doesnt enter an integer varying from 1 to 100.
        else {
            printf("\n Error Grade input, Please Key in Again. (1 to 100 only.)");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nThe GPA is: %.2f", sum);
    if (sum <= 49) {
        printf("\nYou can register for 2 subjects for next semester.");
    } else if ((sum >= 50) && (sum >= 79)) {
        printf("\nYou can register for 5 subjects for next semester.");
    } else if ((sum >= 80) && (sum <= 100)) {
        printf("\nYou can register for 6 subjects for next semester.");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n_______________________________________________________");
    printf("\nEnd of program");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to read an arbitrary input, check it against rules, ignore any input not matching the rules and keep asking for input until the rules are met? Your code seems already quite close. What got you stuck?

Comment: I don't know of *any* character encoding where e.g. `2 == '2'`. Definitely not in [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii).

Comment: Furthermore, consider re-reading your `if` statement. What is that semicolon doing there?

Comment: First of all format your code properly. Respect our time 

Now as `@Some programmer dude` mentioned you need to convert char to the number.

    `temp = temp - '0';` 

You need to check the returned value of the scanf. As the last remark - use functions to complete tasks. Don't write everything in the main function. I did not check anything else, as the code is just so horrible written and formatted.

Comment: I am not allowed to create functions yet since lecturer has not introduced those chapters yet. I can only use main method. I have to use what is under current syllabus.

Comment: Another scanf() used for reading user input without checking the return value. If the user enters something that is NOT a number, your variables do not get initialized, and you are deep into undefined behaviour. DO use fgets() to read a whole line of input NOT overflowing your input buffer, and then parse that buffer in memory (using e.g. strtol()).

Answer (score 0):

A `do-while` loop is perfect for loops that need to be called at least once and will get rid of your duplicated code. Reading unstructured input, possibly from the keyboard, (one could call, `./a.out < text.txt`,) is actually something that is tricky to get right.

Luckily, the `C` FAQ has lots of advice, eg, http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html. It's going to be very arduous without functions, though. From limited testing, I'm pretty sure that this is a solid way to read the first variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* fgets sscanf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_ printf fprintf */
#include <string.h> /* strlen */

int main(void) {
    int no;
    /* Input number, no \in [2, 6], and make sure that the read cursor is on
     the next line. */
    do {
        char buffer[80];
        size_t len;
        printf("Enter number of subjects you took for current semester, [2, 6]: ");
        /* On the advice of http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html, this reads
         into a buffer first. */
        if(!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
            if(feof(stdin)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Premature EOF.\n");
            } else {
                /* On IEEE Std 1003.1-2001-conforming systems, this will print
                 a meaningful error. */
                perror("stdin");
            }
            /* Can't really do anything interactive once stdin has a read
             error. */
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        /* This is always going to be true, but segfaults if not. Paranoid. */
        if(!(len = strlen(buffer))) continue;
        /* Normally fgets stores a '\n' at the end; check. */
        if(buffer[len - 1] != '\n') {
            /* Check if the length of the buffer is big enough to hold input. */
            if(len >= sizeof buffer - 1) {
                int c;
                fprintf(stderr, "Line too long.\n");
                /* Flush whole line. http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html */
                while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
                    if(c != EOF) continue;
                    if(feof(stdin)) fprintf(stderr, "Premature EOF.\n");
                    else            perror("stdin");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                continue;
            } else {
                /* Non-POSIX lines, eg, file without '\n' terminating. */
                fprintf(stderr, "Note: line without line break detected.\n");
            }
        }
        /* Parse buffer for a number that's between [2, 6]. Ignore the rest. */
        if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &no) != 1 || no < 2 || no > 6) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
            continue;
        }
        /* Now no \in [2, 6]. */
        printf("no: %d\n", no);
        break;
    } while(1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

One may be able to get away with a subset of this if your teacher enters only well-formed numbers.

Comment: `if(!(len = strlen(buffer))) continue;` duplicates the check of `if(!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))` -- the only way you pass the first test is if there are characters in `buffer`. `if(buffer[len - 1] != '\n')` does not guarantee `"Line too long.\n"`. (a non POSIX `EOF` or user generated `EOF` with, e.g. `[Ctrl+d]` will do it) Instead check `if (len && buffer[len-1] == '\n') buffer[--len] = 0; else if (len == sizeof buffer - 1) { /* then too long */ }`. Don't skimp on `buffer` size. `512` or `1024` is fine.

Comment: I have not come across a source that says, definitively, that `fgets` will fill at least one character to return true in all machines. Essentially, moving the check to the next line with `if(len && ...)` accepts non-`POSIX` lines, without the `\n`, that my code would reject. Therefore, `EOF` before the end of the line will lead to, `"Line too long.\n"`; the message is inaccurate. The buffer is rather small in general; one can use, `LINE_MAX` defined in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: `man 3 fgets RETURN` "*fgets() returns s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.*"

Comment: I added a check that differentiated between non-POSIX and overlong lines, `len >= sizeof buffer - 1`. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some semantic mistakes. You must never put a semicolon after a `if` statement. Also you can write a more legible code by spacing blocks of code. Even better, you could refactor some blocks and encapsulate it into functions. Aside of that, see this solutions:

For the first problem, it can be solved with few lines of code. It's a good practice that the user know the restrictions of inputs before enter his input:

```
/* ### I want to limit this integer input to be >=2 && <=6. */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int no;

    do {
        printf("Enter number of subjects you took for current semester (2~6): ");
        scanf("%d", &no);
    } while (no < 2 || no > 6);

    return 0;
}
```

The other issue can be solved by using the Standard C Library. Just `#include <string.h>` and `#include <ctype.h>`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* strlen() */
#include <ctype.h> /* isdigit() */

int main()
{
    int n, invalidInput, status;
    char strInput[5];
    int i; /* for loop */

    do {
        invalidInput = 0;
        printf("Enter a **number** between 1 and 100: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        status = scanf("%4s", strInput); /* read at maximum 4 chars from stdin */
        if (status > 3) {
            continue; /* try again */
        }

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(strInput); ++i) { /* ensure that all characters are numbers */
            if (!isdigit(strInput[i])) {
                invalidInput = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!invalidInput) {
            n = atoi(strInput); /* now your input is a integer */
            if (n < 1 || n > 100) {
                printf("Error: the input must be between 1 and 100.\n");
                invalidInput = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (invalidInput); /* repeat until all chars are digits and they are in the required interval */

    return 0;
}
```